# Reference a nested schema in moongose

Tags: mongoose

I have a Albums Schema which has a sub-scheme of Songs.

```
AlbumSchema
albumName:
songs:[{name,url}]
```

I have another collection which has a schema of Playlists. 
Each document in this Schema is supposed to hold an array of songs.

```
PlaylistSchema
playlistName:
songs:[]
```

How do i go about referencing Songs from Playlists,so that i can use populate on Playlists ? 
Is there a way to do it without breaking out Songs into its own collection ? I have tried searching SO and the moongoose docs but so far can't figure out a way to do this.

Note:This question was flagged as being a duplicate. ITS NOT ! The question the moderator linked to is asking about how to populate references in one collection with documents in another collection. This question is about referencing a SUB-DOCUMENT in a collection from another collection. Two VERY different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can't have references to subdocuments. There's no way around it. So you can't use populate. You will need to a query on the `Albums` collection and use `project`(`$elemMatch`). Consider changing your schemas if you want to use `populate`.